# Front microphone not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, soundcard

After installing (20.04 LTS) I had an issue with my earphones...  Initially my mic and my earphones both weren't working. But after a bit of research I was able to fix the speakers but mic is still an issue.

Output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`

`Codec: Realtek ALC662 rev3`
Then after knowing the codec of my sound card I visited https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html and picked up my model and added the following line in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

`options snd-hda-intel model=alc662-headset-multi`
This fix seemed to work when I selected Analog Stereo Duplex(unplugged) in Pavucontrol and the audio came in speakers but mic was still dead but somehow it was able to capture all the voices coming out of speaker of headphone. I went to settings but there was no option to select input device device.

[image: Screenshot of Sound Settings]

I installed a audio recorder and there I could find an option to select external mic and it worked quite well.

[image: Screenshot of Audio Recorder]

How to fix this problem?

Additional Notes:

[image: Screenshot of Alsamixer]

The problem is in front panel only rear mic and speaker works. My PC is very old so I have two separate jacks for mic and speakers. I use a splitter.

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshots in-line, rather than as links.

Comment: I am new to this... It doesn't allow me to... IT says I am not permitted

Comment: I've edited your question to put the images inline for you, but the edit is awaiting moderation.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now what is the fix to the mic problem?